# How to achieve Page numbering Chapter/Section wise in PDF creation using WKHTMLTOPDF PDF engine

Tags: html, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate a PDF book using WKHTMLTOPDF for Linux and lunching through a Perl program. I am passing multiple html files with cover page and footer info through html file to WKHTMLTOPDF command line. While printing as PDF WKHTMLTOPDF treats each file as one section/chapter. I can achieve the page numbering on full PDF through variables using Javascript given in footer html. But I want to print the page number of the current chapter/section is in processing and also total no of pages in that chapter/section. Actually it should reset the page number counter after printing chapter/section. This info can be useful to show the total no of pages in each section and page numbering section wise.

Can anyone know how to achieve it? I am using WKHTMLTOPDF patch QT RC11

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `[sitepage]` and `[sitepages]`, e.g.:

`wkhtmltopdf.exe file:///C:/temp/html1.html --footer-right "Page [sitepage] of [sitepages]" file:///C:/temp/html2.html --footer-right "Page [sitepage] of [sitepages]" output.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to solve your problem.

1. You can provide a `--page-offset` value with each page file object. For instance: `wkhtmltopdf page --page-offset 1 section1.html page --page-offset 1 section2.html`
2. You can calculate the number of pages in the current section by using the query string provided to the footer html script

Comment: Thanks for info. Do you have some examples?

Comment: I had no luck with this. section1 started on page 2 of <total>, and section2 just started where section1 left off.